# @Override specified for non-overriding method: void truck.speed()

Tags: apex, method, inheritance

base class

```
public  virtual class vehicle {
    public  void model()
    {
        system.debug('these is the vehicle model');
    }
    
    public virtual void speed()
    {
        system.debug('this is speed for vehicle');
    }
}
```

child class:

```
public class truck extends vehicle
{
    public override void speed()
    {
        system.debug('these is the 50milesper/hr');
    }
}
```

my error is
@Override specified for non-overriding method: void truck.speed()
Non-virtual and non-abstract type cannot be extended: vehicle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mahesh, I tried to create the classes as per your code. I am not facing any issues. Can you check it you are using the same. Make sure your parent class is Virtual

Comment: Are you sure the "vehicle" class is successfully deployed to the org before or at the same time as the "truck" class? Are you doing this through the Setup UI, using anonymous Apex or using an IDE like VSCode?